# My TextView expands to hold larger amount of text but that distorts the layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here are images of my application with two different inputs:
60! and 125!

[image: This is result with 60!]

With 60! buttons are not distorted.

[image: This is result with 125!]

with 125! buttons are gone.

Comment: use max height in textview, or multiline textview with scrollable content.

Comment: did the solution helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:maxLines` and `android:ellipsize` attributes to your `TextView` XML as below...

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```